# How to get an ROI based tooltip in Python + any imaging library

Tags: python, user-interface, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Running Python, I have an image and some data calculated for different ROIs (regions of interest). 
I would like to display that image, and have a tooltip pop up whenever I am over one of those regions of interest.

This is mainly for debugging purposes - so I don't care that things will be very pretty, or integrate into any other sort of GUI - just that I can easily understand what value I calculated for each part of the image.

Also - I don't mind which imaging/display library to use for that purpose. I normally work with PIL, or directly with numpy arrays - but other libraries are just as good for me.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a quick GUI with [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for debugging you can simply get the position of mouse clicks and print the value for the corresponding ROI. I would use OpenCV as it has [SetMouseCallback](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=setmousecallback#cv.SetMouseCallback)() and you can define  ROIs by polygons and then test what polygon gets the click, see this [example](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html). If you've never used OpenCV before then maybe this is not the best option.

Comment: I've never used OpenCV - so it won't be my first option. Other than that - sounds good.